# Undoing a git rebase --skip - reapply a commit during a rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'm doing a long `git rebase` with a lot of commits. I accidentally `--skipped` a commit where there were some conflicts which I resolved. I should have done `git rebase --continue`.

Is there are way to re-apply this previous commit during this rebase phase and then continue the rebase?

One way I see is to

1. stop the rebase at this point by creating a branch on the last commit which was correctly applied
2. restart the rebase starting with the previously skipped commit.

Or can I do a cherry-pick whilst being in a rebase-phase?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I found a way which "worked for me":

During a rebase lots of things are happening in the `.git/rebase-apply` directory. Amongst others there is a file called `next`. `next` is containing a number which corresponds to a file which is residing in the `.git/rebase-apply` as well. This file contains information about the commit which is currently being processed. For example:

```
$ cat .git/rebase-apply/next
0260
$ less .git/rebase-apply/0260
<info about the commit which is currently processed (and has conflicts)
```

Git seems to keep the commits which are skipped as the above mentioned files. Whereas files corresponding to commits which have been applied are not there anymore. The commit I accidentally skipped was called 0259 and the file was still present.

Here is what I did:

```
$ echo "0258" > .git/rebase-apply/next
```

With that I told git that currently the 258th commit is processed (which previous applied correctly). Then I did

```
$ git rebase --skip
```

to tell git to forget this one and, voila, I could again work on the skipped commit, correct the conflicts and `--continue`. It has worked.

Comment: This changed a bit in recent git versions, but I was still able to make it work by tweaking these files: `git-rebase-todo` and `onto` following the idea above.

Comment: Using git version `1.9.4.msysgit.1` I could succeed with the approach from Patrick B. I did neither use `git-rebase-todo` nor `onto`.

Comment: I'm afraid this is no more possible after a git rebase --skip. At least for me. I don't have a "rebase-apply" in my ".git" folder

Comment: For me today with git 2.20.1 the directory was `.git/rebase-merge/` and the files I modified were `git-rebase-todo` and `done`. I ran `git reset --hard <hash-of-parent-of-skipped-commit>` to clean up the working directory, and finally `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: This is a life saving reply.

Answer (score 63):

Git is great because it saves a log of basically everything you commit.

1. Find your commit in "**.git/logs/HEAD**" and open in a text editor
2. Find your SHA in the HEAD file

   > 3c8c... **2260dc...** Full Name {my.email@email.com} 1471276956 -0600  commit: Saving Trial 1,2,3
3. Type (note type enough of the sha so git knows which one to pull):

   > git checkout -b recovery **2260d...**

See link for reference: http://blog.screensteps.com/recovering-from-a-disastrous-git-rebase-mistake

Comment: There is a dedicated command `git-reflog` to query the commit history, there is no direct need to open the file.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I found the rebase hash in `.git/REBASE_HEAD` and copied the hash. Then in my branch where I did the `git rebase --skip`, I did a `git merge {copied hash}`. And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers are great, but I found an even quicker way to recover the single commit I had just rebase-skipped/'lost':

1. scroll up through your terminal output where you just made that commit
2. copy the commit hash,
3. run `git cherry-pick -x <commit-hash>` on a fresh branch.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you messed up with the commits and you want to go back to the previous working state. Always remember to do these 3 steps.

1. git reflog
2. Copy the Hash id of the commit you want to go back to from the log printed by the above command.
3. git reset --hard *{past-your-hash-id}*

Thats it.