# Back up to a previous conflict during git rebase

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

I'm rebasing a feature branch on to master, non-interactively: `git rebase feature master`.

During this process a series of conflicts come up and I resolve them manually one at a time. However, on conflict #3 I forget to save a file with a series of extensive changes, and just blindly `git add` the file, conflicts and all, and `git rebase --continue`.

Now I'm at another conflict, and the because of the previous conflict the file looks like a huge mess. `git rebase` offers me `--continue`, `--skip`, and `--abort`, and I don't want to do any of those: I want to "back up" to the previous commit and save the changes I forgot to save before "re-applying" the patch at this step of the rebase.

What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I did to fix the situation, for future reference. This post gave some hints:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/38959162/586086

1. Save a copy of the file I forgot to save.
2. `git rebase --abort`.
3. Look in `.git/logs/HEAD` for the commit SHA where I screwed up. (These are saved, even after aborting the rebase.)
4. `git checkout -b recovery SHA`.
5. Save the conflict-resolved version of the file on top of the conflicting version (the save I missed) and `git commit -m "resolve conflicts"`.
6. `git cherry-pick` the remaining commits of the rebase onto `recovery`. Finish the rebase (saving changes more carefully this time :).
7. `git checkout feature` and `git reset --hard recovery`.

If I do this process above, there will be the extra `"resolve conflicts"` commit above. If it matters, I can get rid of this by doing a `git rebase -i` on top of `master`, and squashing it into the commit it was supposed to be a part of.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is one case where Git is pretty weak.

There's stuff in the underlying system that would make "back up to where I was a few steps ago" easy (well, it *would be* easy, even with interactive rebase, if Git saved the rebase-to-do instruction sheets from each step, which it doesn't but could do pretty easily).  But there is nothing in the rebase code that actually achieves that.

If you put a lot of work into your commits-so-far, you can set a branch or tag name right now, at your detached HEAD:

```
git tag temp-save
```

for instance—and then use `git rebase --abort` to quit the *entire* rebase.

Otherwise, use `git rebase --abort` to quit the *entire* rebase anyway.

Then, start over with your `git rebase`.

When you hit a conflict that you already resolved, you can re-use any of the commit you made in your earlier, now-aborted, rebase by running:

```
git log temp-save
```

and finding the commit you made in the previous run.  Use:

```
git reset --hard
git read-tree -u <hash>
```

—or simpler, but I haven't tested it:

```
git read-tree --reset -u <hash>
```

—with the hash found in the `temp-save` output from the terminated rebase to load your index and work-tree from the work you did earlier, as found by `git log temp-save`.  You can fix it up further if ndeeded, and `git rebase --continue`. Once you're past the point that you wanted to rewind from, you can delete the temporary branch or tag:

```
git tag -d temp-save
```

and the commits you made in the first round of rebasing will become very hard to find.

Comment: I independently tried something else while you were typing your answer. What do you think of the process I wrote below?

Comment: That method works too - you're manually doing the rebase by doing each cherry-pick, one at a time, and then moving the branch. That's exactly what `git rebase` does (at least the interactive one—the non-interactive one tries to optimize some of it away sometimes, etc).